# Can we wrap multiple model updates in single transaction for a cakephp Controller action

Tags: php, cakephp, transactions, cakephp-2.3

Can we wrap multiple model updates in single transaction for a cakephp Controller action.

I found these links which solve this issue.

[CakePHP 2.3.x database transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032532/cake-php-2-3-x-transaction#new-answer)

[How to put begin-commit transaction in controller: cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523562/how-to-put-begin-commit-transaction-in-controller-cakephp)

But both of them requires code in specific controller-action. Can above solutions be centralized somewhere, so that **single global transaction is automatically available to all controllers & actions in application**. I'm not able to visualize the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm know sure if i got your question right.
I assume you want a specific action in all controllers?

You probably could implement it in AppController like

```
public function myGlobalAction(){
//dosomemodelstuff();
}
```

Comment: It is not specific action in all controllers, instead it is like wrapping all controllers actions in transaction->begin() and transaction->commit or rollback method.